# How to create factories for same object type but different ways of creation following Domain Driven Design rules? (C++)

Tags: design, architecture, c++, domain-driven-design, factory

Brief description of a problem - providing factories which are creating same object type in different ways and following rules of DDD (isolated domain model, independent domain objects inside of it).

I have some **domain objects in my program** and **couple of functionally different blocks** which are satisfying some needs of my domain model and it's objects. Now i'm facing following issue - some of the **functional blocks outside of my domain model need to create domain objects** (e.g. data base adapter - when i'm loading object back i need to recreate it) - but it also means that **my domain model core is no longer such isolated** as i would like to (and also, as far as i understood, according to DDD concepts domain is isolated and should not be affected by changes in another functional blocks);

**Author of DDD proposes to use factories to create objects** - and conceptually this might solve my problem - and, for example, it's explicitly mentioned in the book (Part 2, Chapter 6, p. 145 "Reconstructing Stored Objects") that for reconstruction of objects you need to have separate factory - because objects would be created differently.

**Another side of this problem** i'm currently facing **is unit tests** - i can have unit tests in another functional block which is using domain objects to test behavior but it also mean that **inside of tests i need to create objects** to actually perform test - and again, i need to set only limited amount of fields and i don't care about the rest - but if i do it explicitly in test then when i'll be modifying my domain model i'll need to update already 2 separate functional blocks from which my model domain normally should be independent - DB layer and unit tests in some another layer.

I think it's possible to solve by providing factories for different ways of creation of same object type instance - but i'm missing examples and **i can't figure out on my own how the implementation could look like because of constrains of Factory patterns** - you need to have single interface function (e.g. create() or create(argsList)) - but that's exactly my problem - i want to keep object with only one ctor and after some modifications of this domain object i want to avoid updating other functional blocks - i would rather like to update 1 factory responsible for this particular part of object's functionality.

I would be really grateful for any examples of such particular use case or advice, thanks in advance!
P.S. i found some example in TypeScript (http://www.taimila.com/blog/ddd-and-testing-strategy/) but seems like it's impossible in C++ with our mechanism of default arguments

Here is scheme of solution i was trying to create:
[image]

How, according to DDD concepts it's possible to implement such a factory? API for me is not clear. I can imagine that if, for instance, domainFactory has some unique attributes (like CustomType field) we can inject this additional variable in factory's ctor - but only in case if this variable is shared between instances - it does not work if variable is unique per object instance.

I can also imagine the case when all other factories are using DomainFactory - but what if another specific factory (e.g. StorageFactory) will try to pass something that Domain one does not expect (e.g. loaded unique id) - and how they can communicate using only one API "create" method?

Comment: Could you just expand on a few points a bit, could be relevant. (1) What is your usage scenario (or workflow) for [the object with loaded id but no CustomType attribute] vs [the object with a newly generated id and with CustomType attribute] - in what context is each of them used, and when each of these appears within the whole lifecycle of the domain concept (so creation, usage, storage to DB & reconstitution, and so on)? (2) What determines when the CustomType becomes available? 1/2

Comment: (3) Are all these factories supposed to be creating the same type of product (either abstract or concrete; i.e. is the issue confined to a single type or a hierarchy), or is Domain Object A one example of several disparate domain types? (4) In your example, Domain Object A seems, at first glance, like a behaviorless data structure (a simple "data bag"), but you say that you want to test this object - does the object implement some behavior, but it's just not shown, or is it perhaps contained within the CustomType? 2/2

Comment: @FilipMilovanović 
1) Use scenarios are following: 
- you startup application, domain model is created and domain objects are initialized. Domain objects in this use case are supposed to be created by DomainImplFactory and in this use case we have all the data to create full object and also only in this use case we'll once generate uniqueId for object.  
2) At some point in time application layer decides to save domain objects - after that at some point we'll load objects using some DB adapter and we need to recreate Domain Object A - but we don't to generate id, but we need to set it

Comment: 2) CustomType is some specific variable which is available only when we create object inside of domain - it's provided by an application layer (imagine that it's kind of "internal infrastructure object") - when we will save object using DB adapter we're not going to save this CustomType attribute - it's needed only for "internal kitchen" within an aggregate - as a result when we'll load object back this CustomType attribute would not be loaded => it's no longer possible to fulfill object's ctor requirements => we can inject this CustomType attribute only in the application layer

Comment: 3) All factories in my example are creating instance of same object type (there is no hierarchy). This might seem like a misuse of factory patterns but factory is something that author of DDD proposes to use for the needs i have described in my use cases (as far as i understood this)

Comment: 4) Domain Object A contains attributes and methods for manipulations with it's internal state or methods for querying it's internal state. This is a basic concept in DDD (objects are containing both their attributes and methods to manipulate/query state), as far as i understood, and that's why i have not mentioned this explicitly in a diagram. 
I have mentioned only attributes to clearly identify my concern - i'm trying to show that there are different places in app where we create same object type but we're creating it differently - sometimes we have all data required, sometimes only part

Comment: I would say what you need Is not one factory interface with multiple implementations, but rather multiple factory interfaces with an implementation for each of them, each interface taking different parameters but producing objects of the same type or at least subtypes.

Comment: But maybe if one factory Is not supposed to return one of the product properties because it Is not used in that use case than maybe you should return different types. Returning object with an unitialized property only because you expect the consumer to not need it Is wrong. You should have one type for the "incomplete" object And another for the "complete" one. Extending the incomplete one or better owning an instance of the incomplete object And than the additional data.

Comment: Please focus on the problem you have not what your think DDD is. For example I would not stick to the factory pattern, it seem to not help your case. Of course its legit to ask how to apply a pattern like DDD to a problem, but just dropping dozens of debateable DDD definitions and attempted solutions won't solve your problem, and makes writing an answer hell.